# Resize Excel table with a number of rows & columns - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, resize

I m trying to resize a table with a number of rows & columns without any luck. Below are the line of code with the error. Any help with appreciate.

`tbl.Resize(2,3)`

with the appove i tryin to increase `tbl` rows by 2 and `tbl` columns by 3.

Comment: What is the error message? If `tbl` is a `ListObject`, then `tbl.Resize` takes a `Range` as parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.resize

Comment: Yes is a listobject & it s take a range.

Comment: So that's your problem, then, `(2, 3)`  is not a range.

Answer (score 1):

```
tbl.Resize tbl.Range(1,1).Resize(tbl.Range.Rows.Count + 2, tbl.ListColumns.Count + 3)
```

This will increment your table by two rows and three columns.

Comment: this convert the table to 3 rows & 3 columns

Comment: I've updated my answer. Didn't read your question properly :)

Comment: You don't need `(1,1)`, `tbl.Range.Resize(` will work.